# How to iterate the rows in sqlite3 with sqlite3_step?

Tags: c++, sqlite

In the SQLite3DB.cpp, I have some code blow:

```
   void QueryJsFileBegin() {
       SQLite3Initilize();
    }

    bool QueryJsFileNext(JS_FILE* js_file) {
        int err = sqlite3_step(stmtQueryJSFILE);
        if (err != SQLITE_ROW) 
            return false;
        // get data.
        return true;
    }

    void QueryJsFileEnd() {
        sqlite3_reset(stmtQueryJSFILE);
    }
```

These works fine when I test them in the SQLite3DB.cpp

```
void test () {
    db::JS_FILE js_file;
    for (db::QueryJsFileBegin(); db::QueryJsFileNext(&js_file); db::QueryJsFileEnd()) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, js_file.js_file_name_.c_str(), "", 0);
    }
}
```

but When I use these in the other cpp(like main.cpp) file, It always return the first row and dead loops. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, in the `step` part of for, you're running `sqlite3_reset()`, so it is closed after first row.